# Static page in smart target

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget

I am getting blank web page when trying to render static smart target page following is the smart target log details

```
2015-02-11 14:53:21,290 INFO  ConfigurationUtility - Loading Mappings for Publications
```

2015-02-11 14:53:21,321 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,321 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,321 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:query for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,321 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,321 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,321 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,321 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:search for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,321 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,337 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,368 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,368 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,368 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:promotions for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,368 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:itemTemplate for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:promotionalItems for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:itemTemplate for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,383 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:fallbackContent for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG DotNetServerControlOutputHandler - Fallback content is inside a Promotions tag; rendering as a template.
2015-02-11 14:53:21,399 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:navigation for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:itemTemplate for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:navigationSection for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,415 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:itemTemplate for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:navigationLink for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:items for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.JavaTagOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,430 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - adding custom handlercom.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,446 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Transforming TCDL tag:itemTemplate for target language dotnet
2015-02-11 14:53:21,446 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - Preparing for TCDL transformation by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,446 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,446 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:21,446 DEBUG TcdlTagHandler - tonights tcdl transforming will be handled by com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.DotNetServerControlOutputHandler
2015-02-11 14:53:28,271 INFO  FredhopperDeployerModule - Start deploying transport package 'C:\Tridion\incoming\Zip\tcm_0-4406-66560.Content\' to Fredhopper.
2015-02-11 14:53:28,450 DEBUG FredhopperOutputBuilder - Loaded data providers for thread [17].
2015-02-11 14:53:28,451 DEBUG FredhopperOutputBuilder - Creating a fredhopper item for component: tcm:1048-7193-16 and template: tcm:1048-7190-32.
2015-02-11 14:53:28,452 DEBUG FredhopperOutputBuilder - Generating fredhopper item with publication/universe/locale: tcm:0-1048-1/catalog01/en_US
2015-02-11 14:53:28,458 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=componentname, displayName=componentname, type=text, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_16_tcm_1048_7190_32_componentname, value=ST Promotion
2015-02-11 14:53:28,528 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=componentid, displayName=componentid, type=list, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_16, value=tcm:1048-7193-16
2015-02-11 14:53:28,531 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=publicationid, displayName=publicationid, type=list, valueId=tcm_0_1048_1, value=tcm:0-1048-1
2015-02-11 14:53:28,532 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=publicationtitle, displayName=publicationtitle, type=text, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_16_tcm_1048_7190_32_publicationtitle, value=080 IndiaWebsite
2015-02-11 14:53:28,532 DEBUG FredhopperOutputBuilder - Running fredhopper dataproviders for building fredhopper output on website/locale: catalog01 / en_US
2015-02-11 14:53:28,532 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=categories, displayName=categories, type=hierarchical, valueId=catalog01, value=catalog01
2015-02-11 14:53:28,533 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=categories, displayName=categories, type=hierarchical, valueId=tcm_0_1048_1, value=080 IndiaWebsite
2015-02-11 14:53:28,533 DEBUG TaxonomyProvider - Starting constructing fredhopper hierarchy from Tridion Taxonomy keywords
2015-02-11 14:53:28,533 DEBUG TaxonomyProvider - There are no classifications found for the components
2015-02-11 14:53:28,534 INFO  ComponentPresentationProvider - Encoding used: UTF8
2015-02-11 14:53:28,539 DEBUG ComponentPresentationProvider - Retrieved the contents of the ComponentPresentation

Component **'ST Promotion'**
      
      
        Using Schema **'Promotion'**, Promotion
      
    
  



  
    
      
        **Component Fields**
      
    
  

  
    title
    



      




      Test





    
  

  
    Description
    



      




      Test data





    
  

  
    Image

2015-02-11 14:53:28,539 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=componentpresentation, displayName=componentpresentation, type=text, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_16_tcm_1048_7190_32_componentpresentation, value=

Component **'ST Promotion'**
      
      
        Using Schema **'Promotion'**, Promotion
      
    
  



  
    
      
        **Component Fields**
      
    
  

  
    title
    



      




      Test





    
  

  
    Description
    



      




      Test data





    
  

  
    Image

2015-02-11 14:53:28,543 DEBUG SchemaInfoBuilder - Reading schema file: C:\Tridion\incoming\Zip\tcm_0-4406-66560.Content\Schemas\tcm_1048-7191-8
2015-02-11 14:53:28,563 DEBUG SchemaInfoBuilder - Unable to find label for field 'Content' - returning field name instead.
2015-02-11 14:53:28,601 DEBUG SchemaProvider - Generating schema information for component / schema combination: tcm:1048-7193-16 / tcm:1048-7191-8
2015-02-11 14:53:28,601 DEBUG SchemaProvider - Loading schema metadata file for retrieving schema name for schema: tcm:1048-7191-8
2015-02-11 14:53:28,611 DEBUG SchemaProvider - Generating fredhopper attribute for schematitle: Promotion
2015-02-11 14:53:28,612 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=schematitle, displayName=schematitle, type=text, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_16_tcm_1048_7190_32_schematitle, value=Promotion
2015-02-11 14:53:28,612 DEBUG SchemaProvider - Generating fredhopper attribute for schemaId: tcm:1048-7191-8
2015-02-11 14:53:28,612 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=schemaid, displayName=schemaid, type=list, valueId=tcm_1048_7191_8, value=tcm:1048-7191-8
2015-02-11 14:53:28,612 DEBUG FolderDataProvider - Starting constructing fredhopper hierarchy from Tridion Folder structure
2015-02-11 14:53:28,613 DEBUG FolderDataProvider - There is component presentation metadata available for folder information
2015-02-11 14:53:28,613 DEBUG AbstractHierarchyProvider - Building hierarchy for path: \Building Blocks
2015-02-11 14:53:28,614 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=categories, displayName=categories, type=hierarchical, valueId=tcm_1048_1_2, value=Building Blocks
2015-02-11 14:53:28,614 DEBUG StructureGroupProvider - Starting constructing fredhopper hierarchy from Tridion StructureGroups
2015-02-11 14:53:28,614 DEBUG StructureGroupProvider - There is no structure group metadata available
2015-02-11 14:53:28,615 DEBUG TemplateProvider - Starting constructing fredhopper hierarchy from Template information
2015-02-11 14:53:28,615 DEBUG TemplateProvider - Generating fredhopper attribute for templateTitle: SendContentToFredhopper
2015-02-11 14:53:28,615 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=templatetitle, displayName=templatetitle, type=text, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_16_tcm_1048_7190_32_templatetitle, value=SendContentToFredhopper
2015-02-11 14:53:28,615 DEBUG TemplateProvider - Generating fredhopper attribute for templateId: tcm:1048-7190-32
2015-02-11 14:53:28,615 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=templateid, displayName=templateid, type=list, valueId=tcm_1048_7190_32, value=tcm:1048-7190-32
2015-02-11 14:53:28,616 DEBUG SchemaInfoBuilder - Reading schema file: C:\Tridion\incoming\Zip\tcm_0-4406-66560.Content\Schemas\tcm_1048-7191-8
2015-02-11 14:53:28,629 DEBUG SchemaInfoBuilder - Unable to find label for field 'Content' - returning field name instead.
2015-02-11 14:53:28,663 INFO  ConfigurationUtility - no publication mapping found for tcm:0-1048-1
2015-02-11 14:53:28,667 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=tcm_1048_7191_8_description, displayName=Promotion - Description, type=text, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_tcm_1048_7190_32_description_value, value=Test data
2015-02-11 14:53:28,668 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=tcm_1048_7191_8_title, displayName=Promotion - title, type=text, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_tcm_1048_7190_32_title_value, value=Test
2015-02-11 14:53:28,668 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=tcm_1048_7191_8_image, displayName=Promotion - Image, type=text, valueId=tcm_1048_7193_tcm_1048_7190_32_image_value, value=tcm:1048-397
2015-02-11 14:53:28,682 DEBUG HostedEnvironmentDeployer - Calling http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/config/smarttarget/runjob?job=STJob.kjb&instance=SmartTarget&universe=catalog01to start kettle job
2015-02-11 14:53:29,645 DEBUG HostedEnvironmentDeployer - Run job call returned with:200
2015-02-11 14:53:29,649 DEBUG HostedEnvironmentDeployer - STJob.kjb started successfully
2015-02-11 14:53:29,650 INFO  FredhopperDeployerModule - Finished deploying transport package 'C:\Tridion\incoming\Zip\tcm_0-4406-66560.Content\' to Fredhopper.

Comment: That looks like a deployer log, not a web application log file, so will not give you much useful information about why the page is not rendering SmartTarget content

Comment: Yes you are right this is deployer log but No other file has been generated by logback of my .net web application 

Any suggestion regarding the cause of blank page would be highly appreciated

Comment: Log files must be generated, unless there is an error in your logback.xml itself (one common error is to use backslashes instead of slashes in the log.folder property, or to have a trailing slash)

Comment: I have taken reference from  http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent
to configure conf files and same sort of configuration is done in deployer where files are generating

Comment: Also while going through the cd_core.2015-02-11 .The only error tag which says...
2015-02-11 16:39:56,583 ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while validating file 'null' with schema 'schemas/cd_deployer_conf.xsd'. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Properties'. One of '{TagBundle}' is expected.

Hope this is not the reason if so any suggestion with respect to the same

Comment: Its not possible to make any progress on this without log files, and the only reason I can think of that there are no log files is an invalid logback.xml or permissions issues (the web app cannot create the log files in the specified directory) - maybe you could run filemon or similar (if on windows) to check if there is some issue with that

Comment: It would be nice to have more context about this issue. For instance, are you using DD4T, TRI or your own ASP.Net web app with Tridion DLLs? Are other web pages displaying Tridion content correctly? Was this particular page working and then started to show blank content suddenly? Is this a development environment to test the SmartTarget installation or a running production environment? What do you mean by rendering a static smarttarget page: is it an aspx or cshtml page which renders a smarttarget region dynamically? Is the page also blank when you remove the ST region code?

Comment: Hi Philippe,
I am using own ASP.Net web app with Tridion DLLs Yes other web pages displaying Tridion content correctly i have created a static smart target page using DWT and other TBB such as Add SmartTarget Query ,Add Promotions tbb..

Comment: Only Fallback content is visible on the page.

Comment: Which version of smartTarget are you using? I suppose that you added the "Add to smarttarget" TBB within the component template of the content you want to display, that this CT is set to dynamic and that you published the component itself? You obviously need a promotion rule set in SmartTarget without a trigger specified so that it applies to any page. You should also check that you can see the promotion content in the Fredhopper business manager Preview, else it would mean that the content is not published to Smarttarget.

Comment: Hi Philippe,
Version Is smartTarget 2014 .Yes I have add "Add to SmartTarget" Tbb along with "Default DreamWeaver Component Design DWT" Default finish action tbb and this is dynamic Component Template .Also can you please help me understand how to set promotion rule in SmartTarget without a trigger